# Tendermint node crashed

Tags: node.js, blockchain, tendermint

I am using lotion js in my node js server, which is used as a blockchain technology.
Some times I am getting Tendermint node crashed. As I am new to blockchain concept, I don't know the reason behind the crash.

I did not do any changes inside node modules

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const db = admin.database()

let app = require('lotion')
({
  initialState: {count: 0}
})

function txHandler(state, tx, chainInfo) {
  state.count++
}

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.use(txHandler)
app.listen(port)

db.ref('Deal').orderByChild('createdTime').startAt(Date.now())
.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {

   var txnObject = {}
   txnObject.senderId = snapshot.val().senderId
   txnObject.name = snapshot.val().name
   txnObject.phoneNumber = snapshot.val().phoneNumber
   txnObject.receiverId = snapshot.val().receiverId
   txnObject.amount = snapshot.val().amount

   axios.post('http://localhost:' + port + '/txs', txnObject).then(function(response){
   console.log('saved successfully')
   }).catch(function(error) {
       console.log('failed to save')
       console.log(error)
  })
})
```

This is my index.js file content.

And the error I am getting is:

```
/Users/chandrika/Documents/lotion-js/node_modules/supercop.js/lib.js:97
      throw ex;
      ^

Error: Tendermint node crashed
    at ChildProcess.tendermintProcess.on (/Users/chandrika/Documents/lotion-js/node_modules/lotion/lib/tendermint.js:90:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:363:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:562:12)
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command in terminal

```
$ rm -rf ~/.lotion
```

and then `$node index.js`
This worked for me!!!

Comment: This forcefully removes the hidden file mentioned.